# bug in new version of scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-image

I have been using `from skimage.color import rgb2lab` but when I installed `python 3.9`  and `SciPy 1.5.4` I was getting the error

```
AttributeError: module 'scipy.linalg' has no attribute `inv`
```

Downgrading to `SciPy 1.5.3` makes that import work again. Now I am wandering if I have done something wrong or is that a bug in `scipy`? In case it's relevant I am using `scikit-image 0.17.2`.

Comment: I just installed scipy 1.5.4 and tried `import scipy.linalg; print(scipy.linalg.inv)` and found that the function is still there. I wonder if something went wrong with your upgrade?

Comment: @Juan very interesting. Are you running python 3.9 too?

Comment: Most likely something's wrong with you scipy install. The function is most definitely there.